# Squid proxy has extremely slow connections when there is some load

Tags: openssl, squid, gentoo

We use squid 4.9 on gentoo. Proxying https over a http proxy. It was working fine until an update in the openssl libraries, now connections are extremely slow. Please help, if you know of a way to fix this. Willing to try different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up disabling IPv6, that seems to have solved the issue.